# Is it possible to make progress bar as indicator instead of dot indicator with image slider carousel?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Is it possible to use a bar as an indicator instead of using a dot indicator with an image slider carousel flutter?.

Is it by using 2 containers in the stack widget? then how to animate it?

[Here the goal that I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yfEk.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MartinM suggested, use a `LinearProgressIndicator` and explicitly set its value.

Check out this example:
[image: tap button for linear progress indicator progress]

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double progress = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            LinearProgressIndicator(
              value: progress,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 45),
            OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() => progress += 0.1),
                child: const Text('Tap for progress')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`LinearProgressIndicator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator-class.html) and map active index as value (value from 0 to 1). Eventually style the indicator as you need

Comment: Do you have an example for the code?